# Library to sync different Twitter clients

Tags: twitter

I'm looking for a library to sync Twitter clients across different platforms. I've seen something like this before but I can't remember the name and searching didn't help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have seen [TweetMarker](http://tweetmarker.net/) before.